# Merge / Stack data frames together and incorporate the respective table names into the variable of first column

Tags: r

I have multiple data frames that follow this format:

```
customers_outdoor
id rating
12 1
21 2 
45 3

customers_sports
id rating
23  1
34  2
```

I would like to merge them all together into one data frame in an rbind fashion with the added requirement that the id variable become a concatenation of the id column with the table name. It should ideally look like the following:

```
customers_all
id  rating
customers_outdoor.12 1
customers_outdoor.21 2
customers_outdoor.45 3
customers_sports.23 1
customers_sports.34 2
```

Looking for an easy way to do this without too many loops. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not called a ***merge*** (that would be combining columns). You are binding rows together, which is sometimes called *stacking*.

First add a column to each dataframe identifying the source:

```
customers_outdoor$df_name <- "customers_outdoor"
customers_sports$df_name <- "customers_sports"
```

Stack them up

```
customers_all <- rbind(customers_outdoor, customers_sports)
```

Create your new id column:

```
customers_all$new_id <- with(customers_all, paste(df_name, id, sep = ".")
```

You can drop and rename columns to get the format you want for `customers_all`.

Comment: Thanks for the clean solution. I'll edit the question to include 'stacking' in case others are seeking a similar solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach though I like user3114046 better:

```
## customers_outdoor <- read.table(text="
## id rating
## 12 1
## 21 2 
## 45 3", header=TRUE)
## 
## customers_sports <- read.table(text="
## id rating
## 23  1
## 34  2", header=TRUE)


L1 <- setNames(list(customers_outdoor, customers_sports),
    c("customers_outdoor", "customers_sports"))

dat <- data.frame(x=rep(names(L1), sapply(L1, nrow)),
    do.call(rbind.data.frame, L1), row.names=NULL)

data.frame(id=paste(dat[, 1], dat[, 2], sep="."), dat[, 3, drop=FALSE])

##                     id rating
## 1 customers_outdoor.12      1
## 2 customers_outdoor.21      2
## 3 customers_outdoor.45      3
## 4  customers_sports.23      1
## 5  customers_sports.34      2
```